# How to get a table of field names and sum of field values as columns?

Tags: qlikview

In Qlikview, I am trying to create a table with two columns, one of which is the the name of the different fields and the other the sum of the corresponding field values. How would I go about to do this and what kind of sheet object should I use to create such a table?

I have tried to use a straight table but it shows the field values instead of the field name and I have also tried a statistics box but you can only chose one field for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution at https://community.qlik.com/thread/89595

Create a straight table, use the system field `$Field` as dimension. You might have to mark the selection box `Show System Fields` for the system fields to show. Then create an expression with

`$(=concat('if($Field=' & chr(39) & $Field & chr(39) & ',sum({1}[' & $Field & '])', ',') & concat(right($Field&')',1)))`